# iOS video from youtube

Tags: ios, youtube-api, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have the URL of a video from YouTube that I get from the YouTube API. I'm trying to use MPMoviePlayerController to play that video, but it is not working for me. This is what I have so far:

```
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
self.movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.movieController prepareToPlay];
[self.movieController setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
[self.movieController setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[self.movieController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[self.movieController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:self.movieController.view];
[self.movieController play];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not working"? Does it crash? Is it the wrong video? Is the video stopping partway through? Not playing at all?

Comment: i mean its not playing...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
NSError *_error = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &_error];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.moviePlayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the feeds(if you are taking youtube url) from the feed.Specifically for Content access Tag(may be i am not sure),for any restriction

Comment: im taking from feeds and i retrieve the source from content tag after that i using the code that i post

Comment: You can use this youtube player to play video just you need to pass the video id(7 or 8 or 9 digit code).https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/xcdyoutubevideoplayerviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

ok its not working this way u r supposed to pass a Video url to MPMoviePlayerController not html url. 
u have 2 ways :
use UiWebView 
OR 
[UIApplication openURL:]